# Transact-SQL string self-concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new in SQL and want to create some UDF function for MS SQL Server (MS SQL Server 2012), but the very simple expression is not working. I simply want to concatenate 2 strings and save the result to the 1st one:

```
DECLARE @ret   CHAR (20)
SET @ret = '4'
SET @ret = @ret + '55'
```

After executing, `@ret` remains at `4`! Why? If I introduce another variable for '4', it works. How can I overcome the problem?

Comment: Change Char to VarChar. Char(20) is always twenty long, so it's appending 55 to '4??????????????????' (ish). Why it works in the second case I'd have to guess its converting to varchar to produce the result then overwriting. I wouldn't rely on that though and would use Varchar, because it is a variable length string.

Answer (score 3):

That's because you use the `char` data type.

When you store the value `'4'` in a `char(20)`, it becomes `'4___________________'` (20 characters long, the `_` represents spaces here).

When you concatenate `'4___________________'` and `'55'` you get `'4___________________55'` (22 characters long).

When you store that back in the `char(20)` variable, it will be truncated to 20 characters, and you get `'4___________________'`.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a `CHAR(20)` the first `SET` will actually store `'4' with 19 blank characters` at the end.  This is because the `CHAR` datatype is fixed width, and will pad your data with blank characters until it gets to the size, 20 here.

When you concatenate the `'55'` onto the end, it will be the 21st and 22nd characters in the string, and fall off when you try to store it inside @ret, which can only hold the first 20 characters.

Using an `VARCHAR` will solve your problem, allowing @ret to be the exact size you require.

```
DECLARE @ret VARCHAR(20);
SET @ret = '4';
SET @ret = @ret + '55';
```

Answer (score 1):

As `CHAR` is a fixed length string data type, so any remaining space in the field is filled with blanks.

In your scenario, `SET @ret = @ret + '55'` will try to store 22 character but unfortunately, the variable is already declared as 20 character long so it truncated the result back to 20 character..Hence, you'll have 20 character with truncating last 2 character i.e. '55'.

Use `char` data type only when you are sure about the length of data which particular `char` data type column have to hold....

If you use nvarchar(20) instead of char(20), it will work fine...

```
DECLARE @ret   nvarchar (20)
SET @ret = '4'
SET @ret = @ret + '55'
```

See the **[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3da4e/2)**

Answer (score 1):

Change datatype of the variable to match what you are concatenating: instead of char use varchar

Answer (score 0):

try using 'cast' in your function to ensure the @ret is a string, changing your code to this works; hope this helps.

```
DECLARE @ret   CHAR (20)  
SET @ret = '4'   
SET @ret = cast(@ret as varchar(1)) + '55'
```

Or just change CHAR(20) to NVARCHAR(20) like this:

```
DECLARE @ret   NVARCHAR (20)  
SET @ret = '4'   
SET @ret = @ret + '55'
```